# Rails, PostgreSQL, and History Triggers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, postgresql, triggers

SO...

I am adding history tables populated by triggers for auditing in my project via something like...

```
execute <<-SQL
  CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION process_history_table() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $history_table$
    BEGIN
      IF (TG_OP = 'DELETE') THEN
          INSERT INTO history_table VALUES (DEFAULT, 'D', now(), OLD.*);
          RETURN OLD;
      ELSIF (TG_OP = 'UPDATE') THEN
          INSERT INTO history_table VALUES (DEFAULT, 'U', now(), NEW.*);
          RETURN NEW;
      ELSIF (TG_OP = 'INSERT') THEN
          INSERT INTO history_table VALUES (DEFAULT, 'I', now(), NEW.*);
          RETURN NEW;
      END IF;
      RETURN NULL; -- result is ignored since this is an AFTER trigger
    END;
  $history_table$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  CREATE TRIGGER history_table
  AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON table
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE process_history_table();
SQL
```

...and this will work for production and other environments. The problem is when someone runs `bundle exec rake db:drop db:create db:schema:load db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test` or something similar (most important is the `db:schema:load` portion), this will bypass trigger creation as triggers are not saved in the `db/schema.rb` file.

Perhaps the correct solution is to say that when using rails, developers should never run `db:schema:load` and always run `db:migrate` instead to ensure all migrations can continuously be re-run. However, we have not been operating that way for a long time and I believe it would be quite painful to do so as we may need to update several dozen or more migrations. Any thoughts on how I could incorporate triggers into my application incrementally and have the developer / test environments continue to be built / re-created the same way as today would be very helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you need or want database-specific features that ActiveRecord doesn't understand then you should switch to `db/structure.sql` for keeping track of your schema. `db/structure.sql` is pretty much a raw dump of your schema made using the database's native tools so it will contain triggers, CHECK constraints, indexes on function results, and everything else.

Switching is easy:

1. Update your `config/application.rb` to contain `config.active_record.schema_format = :sql`.
2. Do a `rake db:structure:dump` to get an initial `db/structure.sql`.
3. Delete `db/schema.rb` from your directory tree and revision control.
4. Add `db/structure.sql` to revision control.
5. Adjust your rake habits:

   - Use `db:structure:dump` instead of `db:schema:dump`
   - Use `db:structure:load` instead of `db:schema:load`

Everything else should work as usual (assuming, of course, that you're sane and using PostgreSQL for development, testing, and production).

With this change made, your triggers will be tracked in `db/structure.sql` and recreating the database won't lose them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gem 'paper_trail'` which Tracks changes to your models, for auditing or versioning. [Here is the Link](https://github.com/airblade/paper_trail)

Answer (score 1):

Isn't https://github.com/jenseng/hair_trigger what you need ?

It allows you to register your trigger in your project and then recreate, update them with a command.

NOTE: I always wanted to use it, but could never had the chance to do it in the end for various reasons so I can't vouch for the quality of the gem.

EDIT: No, they should always use rake db:schema:load for an existing DB