# Rails schema dump is not creating tables for non dbo schema tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

Currently, I am having tables with custom schema such as `rpt.person`, `map.finance`.
When I do `rails db:schema:dump` I see only the tables which are having dbo schema.

Is there a way, where/how we can get those.
Also, when creating Models in rails how should we specify for such tables.

Comment: You misspelled `schmea` it would be `schema` like `rails db:schema:dump`

Comment: I need to update my post. But even we did that, it is not creating schemas for other as i mentioned in my post.

Comment: Which database is this? You could try [switching to `structure.sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47879896/479863) instead of `schema.rb`.